# Angular MSAL and Azure B2C logout redirecting 3 or more times

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, logout, azure-ad-msal

When I call the `msalService.logoutRedirect({ postLogoutRedirectUrl: ..appurl })` the msal library goes between the Azure B2C logout route and my app 3 or more times before finally routing to the login screen. I know this redirect needs to happen at least once based on B2C's current functionality. I verified that when I call the logout function that localStorage is getting cleared out with all the Azure B2C token information.

Here's code that my be relevant:

```
{
    auth: {
      clientId: environment.clientIdMS, // This is your client ID
      authority: environment.authorityMS, // This is your tenant ID
      knownAuthorities: [B2C Tenant],
      redirectUri: environment.redirectUriMS // This is your redirect URI
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set to true for Internet Explorer 11
    },
    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
        piiLoggingEnabled: false
      }
    }
  }


// Guard config
{
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    authRequest: {
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', API URL],
      extraQueryParameters: {
        test: 'test'
      }
    }
  };

// Subscription to check if the user is logged in
this.msalBroadcast.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.loggedIn = this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
        if (this.loggedIn)
          this.checkAccount();
      });
```

Also, I'm using the MSAL Guard on all my routes `canActivate: [MsalGuard]` so that should handle send the user back to the login screen if no token is found in local storage.

Comment: I am injecting 'MsalService' from '@azure/msal-angular' and there is a method named 'loginRedirect' for login and another one named 'logoutRedirect' for logout. What is 'this.msalBroadcast.inProgress$' ?

Comment: @MajiD the msalBroadcast comes from importing the MsalBroadcastService from the Angular MSAL library. It broadcasts the events that happen within MSAL.

Comment: Just try Injecting MsalService and use loginRedirect method. works like a charm

Comment: My problem isn't with login, it's with logout. When I call the logoutRedirect that's when my app is redirecting back and forth multiple times.